# Define a list type into a variable

Tags: c#, linq

Hello everybody
I have a LINQ declaration like this :

```
var query = from foo in NHibernate_Helper.session.Linq<TheType>() select foo;
```

Is it possible to store TheType into a variable to dynamically define this one ?

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't do exactly what you asked, but can you just make your method generic?

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetSomething<T>()
{
    return (from foo in NHibernate_Helper.session.Linq<T>() select foo);
}
...
GetSomething<TheType>();
```

Comment: How is this answering the original question - which was "Is it possible to store TheType into a variable to dynamically define this one?". You've not answered it at all!

Answer (score -1):

No, generic types must be known at compile time.

Comment: So i have to make a method for every linq object ?

Comment: @eka808 Yes. And no. What you *really* have to do is re-think the way you are approaching the problem.

Comment: @bzlm Can you give me more details ?

Comment: @eka808 Not really. But "method for every linq object" sounds like a hammer solution to a screwdriver problem. (I just made that metaphor up btw.)

Comment: @eka808 I think you should try to understand whatknott's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997066/define-a-list-type-into-a-variable/3997787#3997787

Comment: love to know why this one got downvoted. Probably not the answer the OP was looking for!

Comment: @Jamiec - I wasn't the down-vote.  However, the answer isn't *exactly* correct.  You can use reflection and the `MakeGenericType` method of the `Type` class to create a generic type on the fly.  I just wasn't able to work out how to use the result in a linq expression.  Example http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/3fa84655-10cd-4c8f-bbb0-067b352ee0f9.